# usestate not working for afterwards components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

[image: click anyone of cards,the star will change and "n" of 5 stars changes too.this is what i expected]

But even i click the rating star in last three cards,all changes happen on the first one,I do not know why.I am not sure what kind of problem is.Can you explain me?I do not only what a simple showcase fulfilled,i want to know why,thanks.
Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default function ColorCard({ title, color, rating, timestamp }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(rating);

  return (
    <Grid item>
      <Card>
        <Typography className={classes.title}>
          {title}
          <DeleteIcon
            style={{
              float: "right"
            }}
          />
        </Typography>

        <Box
          style={{
            backgroundColor: `${color}`,
            padding: "10%",
            margin: "5%"
          }}
        ></Box>
        <Rating
          name="simple-controlled"
          value={value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
        />
        <Typography
          component="legend"
          style={{
            fontSize: "2vw"
          }}
        >
          {value} of 5 stars
          <span
            style={{
              float: "right"
            }}
          >
            {timestamp}
          </span>
        </Typography>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Full project:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-62eh0?file=/ColorCard.js:201-253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `<Rating name="simple-controlled"`. `Rating` is backed by radio inputs that are visually hidden in order to provide accessibility aspects (e.g. keyboard functionality). The `name` property of the radio inputs is controlled by the `name` property passed to `Rating`, so you need to give each rating a unique name.

Here's a modified version of your sandbox demonstrating this: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kytd5?file=/ColorCards.js:365-389

The changes involve passing an `inputName` prop to `ColorCard`:

```
<ColorCard key={color.id} inputName={`ratingFor${color.id}`} ...
```

and then using that when rendering the `Rating`:

```
<Rating name={inputName} ...
```

From the [Accessibility](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/#accessibility) portion of the `Rating` documentation:

> The accessibility of this component relies on:
>
> - A radio group is used with its fields visually hidden. It contains six radio buttons, one for each star and another for 0 stars, which is checked by default. Make sure you are providing a `name` prop that is unique to the parent form.

Comment: thanks Ryan,could I detect this problem via kind of tool?Such as jest?

Comment: @juexu I've added to my answer the portion of the documentation that explains this aspect. I'm not sure I understand your question. It doesn't seem that you had difficulty detecting the problem, only difficulty understanding the cause. The main resources for understanding the cause of the problem are the documentation, and looking in the generated html and `Rating` source code to see how the state is managed.

Comment: thanks@Ryan Cogswell,I am starting to learning Jest test library for reactjs which could compare the result with expectation,so I just wonder there are some bridge to apply jest test library.Whatever,thanks for your heck explain,thanks